# Django: 'wikilink' is not a valid tag library

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm tryin' to make a simple wiki in django. I want to make it so, that I can link to a new page - create new page if it doesn't exist - with CamelCase. 
I'm following a tutorial and I'm there where i have to load my library `wikilink.py` from `view.html` with `{% load wikilink%}`, but get this error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /wikicamp/start/
>
> 'wikilink' is not a valid tag library: Template library wikilink not
>   found, tried
>   django.templatetags.wikilink,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.wikilink,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.wikilink

```
1   {% extends "base.html" %}
    2   

          {% load wikilink%} <----"This is red"



    3   
    4   {%block title%}{{page_name}}{%endblock%}
    5    
    6   {%block content %}
    7           <h1>{{page_name|escape}}</h1>
    8           {{content|wikify}}
    9           <hr/> 
    10          <a href="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/edit/">Edit this page?</a>
    11  {%endblock%}
```

I rly have tried to find out by myself, but I don't know what I'm doin' wrong.. Hope someone can help me!!
Peace

Comment: Where is wikilink.py? Is it in an app? Is that app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty new to this, but yes I think it's an app. When i type 'wikilink' under INSTALLED_APPS, i cannot run 'python manage.py runserver' in cmd..

Comment: Er, why not? If you're getting an error, you should post it. You should also show your file structure. As I asked, *where* is wikilink.py?

Comment: Desktop\wikicamp\wiki\templatetags? :) I cannot post pictures. But in cmd i get this error:
ImportError: No module named 'wikilink'

Comment: So, the app is "wiki". Is *that* in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Omg.. I've tried everything but wiki - so stupid.. Thank you man!!!

Comment: I have another question right now @DanielRoseman. Is it okay if I ask here, or should i make a new 'Question?

Comment: Please ask a new question.